# Resize a banner in CSS

Tags: html, css

I will wish to get a result like this for example in CSS. 
[image]

Here is my result for now

[image]

How to do to have the same result that the first image? 
Here is below my code.

```
.banner02{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;

}
```

And my HTLM

```
<div class="my_banner_reg">
        <img class="banner02" src="images/slider.jpg"/>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to post more code. See [mcve]

Comment: `background-size:cover;` and `background-position:center center;`

Comment: @ j08691: sorry I have edited my first post. I have a little html

Comment: @APAD1 : no changement... :-( snif snif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are written, But add the following styles to your element that have `background-image`:

```css
header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://trak.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/10-Rupees-Coins.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

And another way:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://trak.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/10-Rupees-Coins.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: @anais Good luck :)